# Enabling transparent data encryption on Azure Managed Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

Databases on `Azure Managed Instance` are encrypted by default. And these dbs have Service-managed Transparent data encryption (TDE). One of our database is a restored database from a `.bak` file, and hence its `Encryption Enable` property was set to `False`. We want this database to be encrypted, as well. Question: Can we enable this database just by setting `Encryption Enable` to True. Will it cause any issues. Are there any other steps that need performed for encrypting this database. We heard you have to create Master Key etc. But for our all other databases, that have Service-managed Transparent data encryption (TDE), we don't see any master key.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb
SET ENCRYPTION ON;
GO
```

Comment: How about master key etc. - as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-tde-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#manage-transparent-data-encryption)?