# Permissions for setting a baseline for SQL vulnerability assessment rule

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, vulnerability-assessment

I'm getting a SQL vulnerability error discovered by `Microsoft Defender for Cloud`. The error points to the following [Vulnerability Assessment rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-rules). But when I try to set a baseline (recommended by this rule), I get the following error:

> The client 'tom.doe@mydomain.com' with object id 'eXXXXXX-...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/vulnerabilityAssessments/rules/baselines/write' over scope '/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/mySQLManagedInstance

**Question**: What permissions are required to set the baseline here?

| Rule ID | Rule Title | Severity | Rule Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VA1281 | All memberships for user-defined roles should be intended | Medium | User-defined roles are security principals defined by the user to group principals to easily manage permissions. Monitoring these roles is important to avoid having excessive permissions. Create a baseline that defines expected membership for each user-defined role. This rule checks whether all memberships for user-defined roles are as defined in the baseline. |

Comment: it seems to be a missing right: "does not have authorization to perform action"

Comment: @MBuschi But the question is `what permissions are required to setup a baseline`. The document linked above does not have prerequisites defined, such as, to perform this action you need to be in role abc or xyz.

Comment: good point! let me check